# Prove $A=B \text{ iff } A \subseteq B \text{ and } B \subseteq A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need help proving the statement

$$A=B \text{ iff } A \subseteq B \text{ and } B \subseteq A$$

I understand how to prove this in words but I can't seem to convert those words into logic or symbols. I thought a proof by contrapositive would make sense but I don't know how to begin. Some preliminary steps would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that the definition of $=$ for sets?  If it isn't, you should begin by finding out what the definition is, and writing it down.

Comment: @MJD: Sets are equal if they have the same elements. This is just an easy conclusion from "have the same elements".

Comment: @downvoter May I know the reason?

Answer (score 1):

$$B \subseteq A\ \&\  A\subseteq B \iff[
x\in B \implies x\in A \ \& \ x\in A \implies x\in B]
\\\iff [x\in B \iff x\in A] \iff A=B
$$

Answer (score 0):

Well $A=B$ means that the elements in $A$ and $B$ are exactly same. So, given $a\in A$ it must be in $B$ and hence $A\subset B$ and in a similar way $B\subset A$. A similar reasoning works for the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that two sets are equal if they have the same elements. This means that for every $x$, $x\in A$ if and only if $x\in B$. Now break that "if and only if" and derive the definition of a two-sided inclusion.

If you're careful enough, this derivation can itself be reversible, saving you the need to derive equality from the two-sided inclusion.